# No se asigna un valor de combobox a la clase model (Hibernate Validator)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Estoy intentando cargar valores a un select (o comobobox) dinamicamente desde lado servidor con Spring Boot. Tambien estoy validando este formulario con la ayuda de Hibernate Validator.

Estoy teniendo un problema muy molesto que no me explico porque esta ocurriendo. En mi formulario tengo dos combobox (o select), el primero si esta seteando los valores, mientras que el segundo (el dinamico) no lo esta haciendo. Intente hasta con probar ponerlo todo manualmente, pero el molesto problema persiste.

```
   <form:form id="form" modelAttribute="nuevoEvento" method="POST">
    <div class="containerLeft">
        <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>Nombre del evento</Label></td>
                        <td><form:input type="text" path="titulo" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan=2 style="text-align:center;color:#84FCFF;"><form:errors path="titulo"/></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>Tipo de Evento</Label></td>
                        <td><form:select class="combobox" path="tipoEvento">
                                <form:option value="N/A">Seleccione el tipo</form:option>
                                <form:option value="Importante">Importante</form:option>
                                <form:option value="Informativo">Informativo</form:option>
                                <form:option value="Privado">Privado</form:option>
                            </form:select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan=2 style="text-align:center;color:#84FCFF;"><form:errors path="tipoEvento"/></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>Salon del evento</Label></td>
                        <td>
                        <form:select class="combobox" path="salonId">
                            <form:options items="${listaSalones}"></form:options>
                        </form:select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan=2 style="text-align:center;color:#84FCFF;"><form:errors path="salonId"/></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>Dia del evento</Label></td>
                        <td><form:input type="text" path="fechaEvento" id="txtfecha" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan=2 style="text-align:center;color:#84FCFF;"><form:errors path="fechaEvento"/></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="${principal.name}" />
```

La clase model de este formulario es el siguiente:

```
@TimeRangeConstraints.List({
@TimeRangeConstraints(
    fechaEvento="fechaEvento",
    horaInicio="horaInicio",
    horaCulminacion="horaCulminacion"
)
})
public class NuevoEvento {
@NotEmpty(message="Como se llamara el evento?")
@Size(max=40, message="Titulo invalido")
private String titulo;
@StringComboBoxConstraints
private String tipoEvento;
private String salonId;
private String url;
@NotEmpty(message="Seleccione la fecha del evento")
private String fechaEvento;
@NotEmpty(message="A que hora inicia el evento?")
private String horaInicio;
@NotEmpty(message="A que hora termina el evento?")
private String horaCulminacion;

public NuevoEvento() {}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getTipoEvento() {
    return tipoEvento;
}

public void setTipoEvento(String tipoEvento) {
    this.tipoEvento = tipoEvento;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getFechaEvento() {
    return fechaEvento;
}

public void setFechaEvento(String fechaEvento) {
    this.fechaEvento = fechaEvento;
}

public String getHoraInicio() {
    return horaInicio;
}

public void setHoraInicio(String horaInicio) {
    this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
}

public String getHoraCulminacion() {
    return horaCulminacion;
}

public void setHoraCulminacion(String horaCulminacion) {
    this.horaCulminacion = horaCulminacion;
}

public String getSalonId() {
    return salonId;
}

public void setSalon(String salon) {
    this.salonId = salon;
}
```

}

El atributo que este molestando es salonId.... ahora, como estoy cargando esos elementos? Aqui tienen, desde el controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/usuarios")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
SalonRepository salon;
@Autowired
UsuarioSalonRepository userSalon;

@GetMapping("/home")
public String goHome(Model model, Principal principal) {
    System.out.println(principal.getName() + " HA INICIADO SESION!!!");
    User logueado = (User)((Authentication)principal).getPrincipal();
    String userInfo = WebUtils.toString(logueado);
    model.addAttribute("userInfo",userInfo);
    model.addAttribute("principal",principal);
    return "/basics/home";
}

@GetMapping("/crearEvento")
public String irCrear(Model model, Principal principal) {
    model.addAttribute("nuevoEvento",new NuevoEvento());
    model.addAttribute("principal",principal);
    model.addAttribute("listaSalones",getSalones());
    return "/Usuarios/crearEvento";
}

@PostMapping("/crearEvento")
public String crearEvento(@Valid NuevoEvento nuevoEvento, BindingResult result,
        Model model, Principal principal) {
    System.out.println("CONTROLSITO: " + nuevoEvento.getSalonId());
    System.out.println("Nombre: " + nuevoEvento.getTitulo());
    System.out.println("Tipo: " + nuevoEvento.getTipoEvento());
    System.out.println("Id Salon: " + nuevoEvento.getSalonId());
    System.out.println("Dia: " + nuevoEvento.getFechaEvento());
    System.out.println("Hora Inicio: " + nuevoEvento.getHoraInicio());
    System.out.println("Hora Fin: " + nuevoEvento.getHoraCulminacion());
    System.out.println("URL: " + nuevoEvento.getUrl());
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("principal",principal);
        return "/Usuarios/crearEvento";
    }else
        return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/misEventos")
public String misEventos(Model model, Principal principal) {
    return "/Usuarios/misEventos";
}

@RequestMapping("/editarEvento")
public String irEditar(Model model, Principal principal) {
    return "/Usuarios/editarEvento";
}

@RequestMapping("/borrarEvento")
public String irBorrar(Model model, Principal principal) {
    return "/Usuarios/borrarEvento";
}

public Map<Integer,String> getSalones(){
    Map<Integer,String> salones = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
    Iterable<Salon> ls = salon.findAll();
    salones.put(0, "Seleccione un salon");
    int i = 1;
    for(Salon salon: ls) {
        salones.put(i, salon.getNombre());
        i++;
    }
    return salones;
}

}
```

Si le doy submit, se pueden visualizar los datos que ingrese, mas no el de ese select de "salonId"....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe ser un error tonto, pero créanme que no logro ver donde falla esto

Comment: El método que muestras hace `System.out.println("Id Salon: " + nuevoEvento.getSalonId());` pero el texto que muestras pone `Nombre Salon: null`. ¿Puedes verificar que el código que muestras se corresponde realmente con el comportamiento observado?

Comment: Es el mismo codigo @SJuan76, solo que simplemente le cambie "nombre salon" por ID salon que es el correcto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu bean tienes

```
public String getSalonId() {
   return salonId;
}

public void setSalon(String salon) {
   this.salonId = salon;
}
```

Lo cual significa que, a nivel de beans, lo que tienes es una propiedad `salonId` que es *readonly* (no tiene *setter*). El método `setSalon` está se ignora, ya que se usa siempre el *getter* para identificar las propiedades.

Lo que no me explico es que esperaría que esto te diera un *warning* en el log avisando de que la propiedad `salonId` es *readonly*.

Comment: Exactamente amigo, diste en el clavo con el problema. Eso pude ver mas tarde con calma.... Y si, se me hace muy raro tal cosa pero bueno, ya se logro resolver